# squareup implementation config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, square

i want to implement squareup app to my web application. But don't know about, where to start, which packages, and etc.
i've installed 'square' package, but can't find any info about how to use it in project, or how to catch API requests, handle the products to squareup. Where to start, roadmap(or smth like that) i need. Thank you.

i've coded this, on config.js,

```
const config = {
    squareAccessToken: 'some token',
  };
  
  export default config;
```

in squareService.tsx that code i have, but it have errors, so it's not the available, i think

```
import React from "react";
const { Client, Environment, ApiError } = require("square");

const SquareService: React.FC = () => {
  try {
    const response = Client.catalogApi.upsertCatalogObject({
      idempotencyKey: "{UNIQUE_KEY}",
      object: {
        type: "ITEM",
        id: "#coffee",
        itemData: {
          name: "Coffee",
          description: "Coffee Drink",
          abbreviation: "Co",
          variations: [
            {
              type: "ITEM_VARIATION",
              id: "#small_coffee",
              itemVariationData: {
                itemId: "#coffee",
                name: "Small",
                pricingType: "FIXED_PRICING",
                priceMoney: {
                  amount: 300,
                  currency: "USD",
                },
              },
            },
            {
              type: "ITEM_VARIATION",
              id: "#large_coffee",
              itemVariationData: {
                itemId: "#coffee",
                name: "Large",
                pricingType: "FIXED_PRICING",
                priceMoney: {
                  amount: 350,
                  currency: "USD",
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    });

    console.log(response.result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <div>
        <button onClick={SquareService}>Test</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SquareService;
```

> Module not found: er: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users

the error message is that. thank you all, for any help.